# Tips for getting better scores in Shatter

Tags: shatter

I've been playing a bit of Shatter here and there lately. Being somewhat competitive and a rather capable gamer, and seeing how the game informs me of my friends' scores on each level, my aim was to at least roughly match what my friends did.

However, I must be doing something wrong, as I'm always 10-20 million points behind (I aim for 60 million on Kinetic Harvest, but have hardly gotten 40). So I'm wondering if there are any techniques I'm missing on to cover those missing points.

Should I not obsess about collecting shards and focus on clearing the level quickly? Should I use multiple balls at once (the game recommends it for a better score, though I don't really get how it helps)? Should I try to suck less at the bonus level?

I'm open to suggestions.

Comment: Is this a PS3 game?

Comment: Well, I've tried some of the suggestions here but I've only managed to do worse than usual... I'll keep at it.

Comment: Maybe try looking up some gameplay videos on youtube where they get the sort of scores you'd like, and see if you're doing something significantly different? I'd try to give more information, but other than using multiple balls I really don't feel like I'm doing anything "special".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you haven't answered back yet so I'm just going to assume that it is the PS3 game. The GameFAQ board has a excellent [FAQ](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/960205-shatter/50715528) for this game. But I'll summarize here so you don't say tl;dr.

1. You lose 1x multiplier when a block crosses your line
2. You lose 1x multiplier when a block hits your bat
3. No penalty for a block hitting a shielded bat (is actually worth points)

And

Remember that there are Bonuses at the end of each level for:

1. No Walls Touched (Shard Storm is a
   must)
2. No Balls Lost (never one to actually
   strive for)
3. Shard Storms Used (this is where the
   big points are at)
4. Speed Bonus (For Bosses Only)

Comment: I was actually talking about the PC version, but are there really any differences between the two versions?

Comment: @Aubergine Well GameFAQ's doesn't seem to think there is any difference, so I would say there probably isn't any difference between the two versions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely use multiple balls. That's probably the biggest difference you can make to your score. You'll clear the levels much faster, and you'll gain energy faster, so you can Shard Storm more often. Every Shard Storm you use will add a million points at the end of the world, so you want to be trying to use them as often as possible. Shooting extra balls is also nice because you can aim them, so when there's an exposed bomb block, or just a few blocks left that you're having trouble finishing off, you can shoot a new ball directly at them.

Give multiple balls a try, it's definitely tricky at first, but I think you'll find that your scores are much higher that way. You don't have to be overly cautious because the game gives more 1UPs when you have less lives, so don't worry too much about letting some balls past you, you'll usually get the lives back quite quickly.

Comment: I was actually talking about the score for the entire world, but I managed to get mixed up with the actual numbers. I'll fix my question accordingly. (And I'll actually accept one of the answers once I get some time to try all this out)